# Must the density operator always have real (as opposed to complex) eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, density-operator

Lately, I have been thinking about how to define the density operator in quantum field theory (QFT) such that it reduces to that of quantum mechanics (QM) in the appropriate limits. I am starting with a 1-particle density operator to figure out the kinks and build up to an N-particle density operator. I realized that, by defining $\psi^\dagger$ as a (complex scalar) field creation operator (which, according to "Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur" by Lancaster and Blundell, acts upon the vacuum ket to produce $|\psi\rangle$),
\begin{align}
\psi^\dagger|0\rangle & =|\psi\rangle
\\ \implies 
\rho (x_1) & := \psi^\dagger|0\rangle\langle0|\psi,
\end{align}
with $\rho(x_1)$ the 1-particle density operator, might allow the construction of a density operator that could reduce to that found in ordinary QM. However, when I plugged in the definition of the field operator, I realized that, due to the Fourier transform relating the momentum creation/annihilation operators with the field operators, the density operator could now be complex.

As such, my question (in 2-3 parts) is: Is it possible to define a density operator via use of QFT that, by application onto the vacuum projection, can suitably reduce to the density operator of QM? If so, must it always be real and how is it constructed?

Comment: The operator defined in the question does not have non-real eigenvalues.

Comment: The problem is the $exp(ik^\mu x_\mu)$ that comes in in the Fourier transform relating $\psi$ to $a_k$.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Because it can result in a complex number when $k$ is integrated over with $|k\rangle$ in the integrand. (I think this can be seen especially when taking the logarithm and then differentiating.)

Comment: It's not clear what that means. A complex number where? The eigenvalues are fine.

Comment: It's not the wave function that I think has the problem, it's the Fourier transform of the momentum creation and annihilation operators. However, if you can show that the matrix does not have complex numbers in it, please show me (I think that would be wonderful if I did the calculation wrong).

Comment: If $|\psi\rangle$ is a state in the Hilbert space, $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ is a projector on a one-dimensional subspace, it trivially has eigenvalue 1 corresponding to the eigenvector $\psi\rangle$, and zero on the orthogonal subspace. Nothing particular about QFT in this sense.

Comment: The density matrix is hermitian so you *cannot* have diagonal terms that are imaginary in *any* basis.

Comment: How can this be? If you evaluate the complex scalar field using Cauchy integral theorem, the operator comes out as complex in the momentum basis... I must admit, this flabbergasts me.

Comment: well... elementary properties of hermitian matrices really.  Since $(H^*_{ij})^\top= H_{ji}$, use this on $j=i$ and $H^*_{ii}=H_{ii} \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eigenvalues are the relative populations of the systems in the basis where $\hat\rho$ is diagonal, and relative populations are real non-negative numbers bounded by $1$.

The off-diagonal elements can be complex, but since $\hat \rho$ is hermitian it will necessarily have real eigenvalues.